# Sample: like Binary Tree Traversal in R

Tags: r, sample

I have 7 pairs of variables: i.e.

```
["F1", "R1"] ["F2", "R2"]["F3", "R3"]["F4", "R4"]["F5", "R5"]["F6", "R6"]["F7", "R7"]
```

And would like generate vectors of 7 variables, where each variable is sampled from each group.

The aim is to generate an ergodic sequence of vectors (in this cases, would be `2^7 = 128` possibilities.

Expected results:

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
[1,] 'F1'  'F2'  'F3'  'F4'  'F5'  'F6'  'F7'
[2,] 'F1'  'F2'  'F3'  'F4'  'F5'  'F6'  'R7'
[3,] 'F1'  'F2'  'F3'  'F4'  'F5'  'R6'  'F7'
[4,] 'F1'  'F2'  'F3'  'F4'  'F5'  'R6'  'R7'
[5,] 'F1'  'F2'  'F3'  'F4'  'R5'  'F6'  'F7'
[6,] 'F1'  'F2'  'F3'  'F4'  'R5'  'F6'  'R7'
...
```

Comment: You want vectors of 7 variables. Any of the two variables in each of the 7 input vectors can be chosen? And what are the lengths of the output vectors?

Comment: yes, essentially,7 pairs to be chosen as a vector of 7 variables, with 'F1' and 'R1' cannot be chosen at the same time (i.e.). It;s kind of a binary tree, with node to be F or R

Comment: and column 1 is only chosen from 'F1' and 'R1' , and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill a `matrix` with a single `for`-loop. You just iterate through each column and fill them by repeating the pairs with the `rep` function. I have parametrized the code so that the number of pairs can vary:

```
pairs <- list(c("F1", "R1"), c("F2", "R2"), c("F3", "R3"), c("F4", "R4"),
               c("F5", "R5"), c("F6", "R6"), c("F7", "R7"))
dimension <- 7 
mat <- matrix(0,2^dimension, dimension)
for(i in 1:dimension){
   mat[,i] <- rep(pairs[[i]], each= 2^(dimension-i))
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to conduct a similar one in python? Thanks